# How to use IF Condition for the output of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have output from a stored procedure (which returns 2 rows and 3 columns). I have to check that the value (from 2nd row, 3rd column) from that output is greater than some number (say 1000) so that I can proceed with other function after that if condition is true.

Example:

```
EXEC sp_helpdb MyDB
```

This is my stored procedure to check the log size of the database. Output will be in table format in which one of the column showing the log size.

Now if the log size value is greater than some number say 800MB, I need to proceed with other operation.

So how to check whether the size of the file is more/less than 800MB ?

Comment: You can insert output of stored proc into a temp table and then check the value in that table to decide how you want to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

--you will Get The Log Details From DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)

```
CREATE PROC dbo.Log_Space
AS 
DBCC SQLPERF(logspace) 
GO 

CREATE TABLE #logSpaceStats 
( 
databaseName sysname, 
logSize decimal(18,5), 
logUsed decimal(18,5),
Status  INT 
) 
GO 


INSERT INTO #logSpaceStats (databaseName, logSize, logUsed,Status) 
EXEC Log_Space
GO

SELECT * FROM #logSpaceStats

DROP TABLE #logSpaceStats
```